# one link + one click = multiple events

Tags: jquery

I've found multiple answers and tried them all, none of them working proprely...

I have a plus-minus button, which update quantity of an item, in a input. It works.
I need to add an second event when the user click the +1 button, and also a second event on the -1 button.
Can't get it to run properly when I add the second event !
Here's the code :

```
$("#inc<?php echo"$key"; ?>").bind({

click: function(){

    $(":text[name='qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>']").val(Number($(":text[name='qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>']").val()) + 1);

    var totalItems = parseFloat($("#qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>").val());
    var priceItem = parseFloat(<?php echo"$priceProduct"; ?>).toFixed(2);
    var totalValue = parseFloat(priceItem * totalItems).toFixed(2);
    $("#subtotal<?php echo"$key"; ?>").html("&#128; "+ totalValue).toFixed(2);

},

click: function(){

    prod_id = "<?php echo"$key"; ?>";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateproduct2cart.php",
    data: "itemid="+prod_id+"&act=update"
    });

}
});
```

This prevents the +/- button from firing. And fires another fonction (intended to remove the table row) !!!
Is this portion of code enough ? Need the whole stuff ?
Anyway, thanks for your help :)

EDIT :
the code below works fine... Don't ask me why, but it does ! :)

```
    $("#inc<?php echo"$key"; ?>").on('click', function(){

    prod_id = "<?php echo"$key"; ?>";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateproduct2cart.php",
    data: "itemid="+prod_id+"&act=update&qty=up"
    });

    $(":text[name='qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>']").val(Number($(":text[name='qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>']").val()) + 1);

    var totalItems = parseFloat($("#qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>").val());
    var priceItem = parseFloat(<?php echo"$priceProduct"; ?>).toFixed(2);
    var totalValue = parseFloat(priceItem * totalItems).toFixed(2);
    $("#subtotal<?php echo"$key"; ?>").html("&#128; "+ totalValue).toFixed(2);

    });
```

HTML :

```
<tr name="prodItemi2" id="prodItemi2"><th id="prodItemi2" scope="row">Title of product #2</th>
  <td>black</td><td><span id="itemPi2">€ 39.95</span></td><td> 
   <button class="SCbutton" id="deci2">-</button>
     <input type="text" class="SCinput3" size="2" value="1" name="qtyi2" id="qtyi2">
      <button class="SCbutton" id="inci2">+</button></td><td>
        <span id="subtotali2">€ 39.95</span></td><td>

  <input type="radio" value="XL" name="sizei2"> XL 
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="L" name="sizei2"> L 
  <input type="radio" value="M" name="sizei2"> M </td><td>
  <span id="showSizei2">L</span></td><td>

  <a onclick="removeItem(this)" id="deleteItemi2" href="#"><img alt="" src="img/deleteItem.png"></a></td></tr>
```

Comment: what does the html look like? Are these buttons added to DOM dynamically?

Comment: would help if you put together a demo that replicates the problem in jsfiddle.net

Comment: well, actually, it has PHP in it, so dunno how to have it work in jsfiddle... but the code is now OK if I PUT AJAX 1st ! (see code updated). Still, I have more problems :)

Comment: doesn't have php in it when it hits browser , take html from there